# How to move the layout above of soft keyboard when it is shown

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I have a simple layout for my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonCancel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="cancel" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and when I touch on `EditText` soft keyboard appears but my button hides beyond the keyboard !

but I wanna the `Button`  move up (above of) the keyboard.

I added this line of code to `AndroidManifest` but nothing changed.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` have an opposite behaviour and therefore I don't think they should be used together. Try just `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` , worked for me.